# Does mongodb community operator supports sharding architecture?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, nosql, kubernetes-operator

Does mongodb community operator supports sharding architecture? If no what are the alternate open source operator options which supports the sharding setup

https://github.com/mongodb/mongodb-kubernetes-operator/blob/master/docs/architecture.md

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does. The main features in Enterprise Edition which are not available in Community Edition are these:

- In-Memory Storage Engine
- Auditing
- Kerberos Authentication
- LDAP Proxy Authentication and LDAP Authorization
- Encryption at Rest

See https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/administration/upgrade-community-to-enterprise/

There are a few more functions in Enterprise, but they are minor.

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer is totally wrong. The community operator doesn't support sharded cluster.
Their GitHub clearly states this:

"The Community Operator does not support creation of sharded clusters yet. Please feel free to contribute to the codebase for features like this."  *Apr 2022*

https://github.com/mongodb/mongodb-kubernetes-operator/issues/947#issuecomment-1102320381
https://github.com/mongodb/mongodb-kubernetes-operator/issues/231